# ford connect clutch?

Tags: ford, troubleshooting, clutch, manual-transmission, van

looking for advice

Van facing uphill (steep) in neutral handbrake on, get back in van would'nt pull uphill at all with over revving then clutch smell, had to put it in reverse for a few feet before moving to first then it did move uphill complaining tho, with smell, seems like first warning sign is it just the clutch?  van was not loaded, many thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not exactly sure what advice you are wanting us to give? Could you please edit your question and specify what exactly your question is?

Comment: Facing a steep hill, presuming you coordinated handbrake release with clutch engagement and applying more throttle to move forward, it's a foregone conclusion of the burning smell coming from overheating the clutch. If driving doesn't reveal a slipping clutch, you may have dodged a bullet otherwise clutch replacement may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you double check the parking brake? Do you know for certain if your rear parking brake is automatically adjusted with use? How many miles/kilometers are on the odometer?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).